# C Runtime Error: Dynamically Allocating Memory in a For Loop

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm posting a continuation of my question from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647709/concatenating-a-char-array-in-c-dynamically-handling-memory).

I'm trying to create a string that begins with a `'!'` and adds 6 values read from a sensor (separated by commas) and then sends it over a serial port. A sample output would be: `"!5,5,5,5,5,5"` or `"!34,34,34,34,34,34"`.

My code is mostly working; I'm able to send the value of **one** analog sensor across my serial port, `!215!215!215` for example, but when I un-comment the `for loop` code below I see nothing across my serial port and the program seems, for lack of a better word, useless.

There seems to be a runtime error occuring in my for loop but I can't determine where it happens. **Why does my code below successfully send serial data for one analog sensor without using the for loop, and send nothing when using the for loop?** How can I tweak my code to achieve my desired output?

```
char* convertIntToString(uint8_t integerValue, char* str){
    utoa(integerValue, str, 10);
    return str;
}

char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}


int main(void){
    uint8_t analogValue;
    char *outputStr = malloc(1);

    while (1) {
        outputStr = realloc(outputStr, 2);
        strcpy(outputStr, "!");
        analogValue = ReadADC(0);
        char str[4]; 
        outputStr = concat(outputStr, convertIntToString(analogValue, str));

        //RUNTIME ERROR IN THIS LOOP
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){                  
            char* newStr = concat(outputStr, ",");
            // free the old memory before using the new memory
            free(outputStr);
            outputStr = newStr;
            newStr = concat(outputStr, convertIntToString(analogValue, str));
            // free the old memory before using the new memory
            free(outputStr);
            outputStr = newStr;
        }

        CDC_Device_SendString(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface, outputStr);  //send sring over serial port
        free(outputStr); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Looks like you got the obligatory close vote :) (Not from me)

Comment: `outputStr = concat()` causes a memory leak since you've just lost the only pointer to a block of memory (the previous value of `outputStr`). So much dynamic memory stuff for so little gain...

Comment: Could it be because you try to realloc a free memory block after sending the first string?

Comment: After `free(outputStr);` at the end of the `while (1)` block, the next iteration attempts to `outputStr = realloc(outputStr, 2);`. But the real answer is: learn to use the debugger.

Comment: @dxiv I don't have access to a debugger. This application runs on embedded hardware and I don't have the license for a simulator I could debug on, nice try though.

Comment: @John3136 If I were to abandon the dynamic memory route and just hardcoded the size of outputStr to the max possible length, how would I get around using concat()? I would still need to use concat I believe, but I'm confused on how to do so without causing a memory leak. Perhaps you could provide a code sample?

Comment: Do you at least have a console that you can print the final string out to so that you can be sure the construction is correct? Or simply rewrite some of the code to make it work on a regular host machine. The core logic doesn't need to change, just a few of the target specific calls. Better than just debugging by inspection only.

Comment: @Cody Then the next best answer is: set up your own debugging/logging facility somehow. Be it blinking LEDs on whatever hardware you target, or diagnostic packets on the serial interface, or whatever. Otherwise, achieving anything remotely robust is utopian.

Comment: @kaylum & dxiv Since my program is centered around serial communications i've been debugging by checking the output string in a terminal (like Putty, Realterm, etc)

Comment: The point is to remove parts of your code from the equation so that you can test other parts. It's standard debugging techniques. That is, remove the serial communication and test just the string construction for example. Some suggestions were provided to you.

Comment: I appreciate all the input. I'm seeing a few different suggestions on the source of the error: the concat() function on a null pointer, realloc on a free memory. Can someone provide a simple, concrete answer on the most direct fix for this problem? Would getting rid of my realloc() work?

Comment: None of those suggestions address your core issue (at least not in an obvious way). They are just pointing out other problems. Though it has issues, your code does not have any obvious bug that would result in the behaviour you have described. That's why the suggestions on different ways to debug further. For example, perhaps the string is fine but `CDC_Device_SendString` is not handling the longer string correctly for whatever reason. That is something we can't verify for you.

Comment: @Cody Then you can insert info traces for debugging like `CDC_Device_SendString(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface, "reached line #42");` and use the same terminal to catch them. Granted, that's tedious, but still better than *not* knowing where a crash happens and trying to guess blindly.

Comment: @kaylum `your code does not have any obvious bug that would result in the behaviour you have described` - as has been twice pointed already, `realloc`'ing a just freed pointer *could* result in a runtime exception.

Comment: @divx You are quite correct. I missed that. So yes, agree that fixing that would be the first thing to try.

Comment: As discussed in the previous question: if you can make a sensible guess at the biggest string then you can just use that size: e.g. 5 lots of 5 numbers with a max of 3 digits = 3*5*5. Oops: allow some space for commas, just assume 1 per number, so its 4*5*5. Plus one for the "!" = (4*5 + 1)  * 5 If you init `buffer[0]` to 0 you can just use `strcat()` to append to it. For debugging and learning just use a fixed buffer - say 256. All those mallocs and copies take some time. Using concat (one malloc, 2 copies) just to add a "," is dumb.

Comment: @John3136 Thanks. If you make this an answer i'll give credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded from the comment above and comments in the previous question.

If you are able to calculate the maximum size of a "packet", then you can avoid dynamic memory all together and just use a fixed buffer size. The calculation doesn't even have to be 100% accurate, as long as it errs on the side of "too big".

e.g.: 5 instances of 5 numbers with a max of 3 digits separated by commas: 5 * 5 * 4 (3 digits + a comma). Not 100% right because the 5th group doesn't need a comma, so you are over estimating by one (or is that 5?). Just be aware of the possible cumulative effect of this if you have multiple "known errors".

So assuming you can estimate the max size, perhaps "encode" it via `#defines` - perhaps even fixing some of the "known errors").

So now you have `char buffer[KNOWN_UPPER_BOUND]`, as long as you initialize it correctly (e.g. `buffer[0] = '\0';`, you can just keep appending to it via `strcat()`. If you were talking big numbers, you could keep track of the last index to avoid repeated scans through the string looking for the end.
e.g. (using globals for simplicity)

```
char buffer[KNOWN_UPPER_BOUND];
int last_index=0;

addString(char* str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (last_index + len > KNOWN_UPPER_BOUND)
    {
        /* error handling */
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(buffer[last_index], str);
        last_index += n;
    }
}
```

So what were some of the issues with the dynamic code?

- Potential for leaks (much like the errors I mentioned in the calculation - ok (by which I mean 'not overly harmful in a small program') if you leak 2 bytes once, not so good when you put it in a loop and leak 2 bytes over and over again)
- Speed issues - malloc is out of you control, it could be very slow. A lot of small allocations can fragment memory which may mean later on when you want a bigger block you can't get one.
- Lots of copying and re-copying of data. Your `concat` is an example here - each concat does a malloc and copies both strings. Every time you call it.

You could still use dynamic memory to hold the final string, but build up each "component" in a fixed size buffer.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move the declaration of `char* newStr` outside the loop.
Declaring the newStr as char array will be better than pointer to avoid leakage. something like  `char newStr[50]`